# Why list.sort() doesn't work but sorted() works fine for the given list in this scenario

Tags: python, list

I was trying to sort `list2 = ['four','six','two','three','one','five']` according to `list1 = [4,6,2,3,1,5]` so that my code updates `list2` to
`['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']`.

I tried the following code:

```
list2.sort(key = lambda x: list1[list2.index(x)])
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: 'four' is not in list
```

However, doing the same thing with `sorted()` function and updating `list2` to sorted list gives the required result. Why?

Comment: The in-place sort changes the list. Looking things up in the list (`list2.index(x)`) while it’s being changed is a bad idea. (Repeated `list2.index(x)` is also a bad idea; sort `zip(list2, list1)`. Or, if `list1` is consecutive integers starting at 1, don’t sort at all: `[list2[i - 1] for i in list1]`.)

Answer (score 1):

## Why does it fail for list.sort?

During `list.sort` the instance behaves as if it doesn't contain anything. That means you shouldn't use that list instance in the `key` function.

You can verify this with this script:

```
a = [3,2,1]

def printlist(key):
    print(a)
    return key

print('before sorting', a)
a.sort(key=printlist)
print('after sorting', a)
```

Which prints:

```
before sorting [3, 2, 1]
[]
[]
[]
after sorting [1, 2, 3]
```

In CPython the corresponding code can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Objects/listobject.c#L1940-L1950). I copied the comment preceding that section here because it contains the rationale for this:

```c
/* The list is temporarily made empty, so that mutations performed
 * by comparison functions can't affect the slice of memory we're
 * sorting (allowing mutations during sorting is a core-dump
 * factory, since ob_item may change).
 */
```

Basically it says that any mutations to the list can lead to segfaults and because the `key` function can execute arbitrary code the list is emptied.

That's also the reason why direct modifications lead to errors:

```
a = [3,2,1]
def appendelement(item):
    a.append(item)
    return item
a.sort(key=appendelement)
```

> ValueError: list modified during sort

## Why does it work for sorted?

`sorted` only gets around that issue because it copies the list immediately ([related CPython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2155)) and thus the "copy" is sorted. That means the original `list2` is still intact and can be used.

## A better way

Note that because of `list.index` your function O(n) essentially becomes N**2 instead of N*log(N).

The Python wiki includes a section about [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate) approach which is generally used in these cases:

```
list2 = ['four','six','two','three','one','five']
list1 = [4,6,2,3,1,5]

decorated = [(num, i, name) for i, (num, name) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2))]
decorated.sort()
undecorated = [name for _, _, name in decorated]

print(undecorated)
# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

The `i` from `enumerate` is essentially used to avoid that the names are every compared - because `i` is always different. It could be omitted in this case though.

## Another alternative approach

Here you also have a unique mapping so you could also use translation dictionaries:

```
list2 = ['four','six','two','three','one','five']
list1 = [4,6,2,3,1,5]

num_to_name_map = {num: name for num, name in zip(list1, list2)}

list2.sort(key=lambda name: name_to_num_map[name])
print(list2)
# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library zip function to combine, element by element, the two lists.  Sort the combined list, which will effectively result in the first list being the sort field.  Then a comprehension recovers the now-sorted list2.

```
list1 = [4,6,2,3,1,5]
list2 = ['four','six','two','three','one','five']

list2 = [a[1] for a in sorted(zip(list1, list2))]
print(list2)

>>> ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```